# delphi: combobox search text same as item text case

Tags: delphi, combobox

in delphi, can add combobox items with different case(in my example uppercase). 
`

```
ComboBox1.Items.Add('SYDNEY');
ComboBox1.Items.Add('MOSCOW');
ComboBox1.Items.Add('BERLIN');
ComboBox1.Items.Add('BERN');
ComboBox1.Items.Add('PARIS');
```

`

[image: combobox shows like that]

but when try search, combobox text differs from items case type

and will be inserted into database as 'bERLIN' instead of 'BERLIN'.

```
UniQuery1.SQL.Add('INSERT INTO login (id,user) values (10,'''+ComboBox1.text+''')');
```

Is there way to automatically change text to actual items case

Comment: Please add to your q the code you use to transfer the combobox text to your database field.  See [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: UniQuery1.SQL.Add('INSERT INTO login (id,user) values (10,'''+ComboBox1.text+''')');

Comment: ``UpperCase(ComboBox1.Text)``

Comment: I edited your question to include the code from your comment. Please always edit (see edit button on the left) added info into your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your example you have all city names in uppercase. Thus you can indeed use
the `UpperCase()` function as suggested in a comment.

However, a more general solution would be to instead check
`if ItemIndex <> -1` indicating that an item indeed is selected and then use
`Items[ItemIndex]` to store in the db instead of the `Text` property.

---

Edit after comment:

To update the `Text` property as well as selection, try this:

```
procedure TForm20.ComboBox1KeyUp(Sender: TObject; var Key: Word;
  Shift: TShiftState);
var
  ss, sl: integer;
  SelectedItemString: string;
begin
  with ComboBox1 do
  begin
    ss := SelStart;
    sl := SelLength;
    if ItemIndex <> -1 then
      SelectedItemString := Items[ItemIndex]
    else
      SelectedItemString := Text;
    Text := SelectedItemString;
    SelStart := ss;
    SelLength := sl;
  end;
  Key := 0;
end;
```

Comment: it maybe lowercase or uppercase this is not matter. I want, combobox searches it's text, if text is same as items[..].text then converts case to items.text

Comment: @MamedAliyev that makes no sense. Either you use `ComboBox1.Text` to insert what the user *actually typed*, or you use `ComboBox1.Items[ComboBox1.ItemIndex]` to insert what the user *selected*. Which do you want?